# Unbold subsubsection title

Tags: fonts, sectioning, bold

I'm rather new to LaTeX, I am trying to get my `article` class document set up so that the `section` font is 16 pt and bold, the `subsection` is 14 pt and bold and the `subsubsection` is 14 pt and **not** bold. I managed to get all the right fonts and font sizes, I just cant get the `subsubsection` to be "unbolded".

I heard about the `titlesec` package, but I am unsure of how to use this to unbold my `subsubsection` title.

Here is some of my code: (I dont know how to make a minimal example, sorry)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, final]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\sectionfont{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do. Please follow the link above to learn how to build a MWE ...

Comment: Did you try with `\mdseries` instead of `\selectfont` in the setting for `\subsubsectionfont`? And loading `sectsty` instead of `titlesec`, of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to be using the commands from the `sectsty` package but loading `titlesec`. You can use either one of those packages, but using their own commands; the examples below show possible solutions using each package:

Here's one way to achieve it using the extended `\titleformat` syntax from `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's an example using the simplified `\titleformat*` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

 \end{document}
```

And here's an example using `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Just for completeness's sake, here's one solution without additional packages, redefining the original commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

 \end{document}
```

As **egreg** mentions in his comment, the presence of `\bfseries` allows not to specify `\selectfont`.

Comment: You can get away with `\selectfont` if `\bfseries` is used.

Comment: @egreg of course; I edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @All, for some reason when I use the \usepackage{titlesec} it gives out an error saying that package is not found, can someone tell me how to install it.. :)

Comment: @uDaY the process may vary depending on your LaTeX installation. Use the search function of the site ans search for manually installing packages.